# accessing the same named files from directories

Tags: python, for-loop, glob

I have two directories that contain text files having same name. Though the file names are same they contain different data and I want to access same named files from both the directories at a time and wants to do some calculation. For testing purposes I have written below code but the loops does not access same named data file at a time....it choses random text files from both directories. Can anybody please suggest me how to access same named files by the below code?

nb: I have to access nearly 1000 files

```
import glob
data1=glob.glob('/home/liu/Music/datafiles1/*.txt')
data2=glob.glob('/home/liu/Music/datafiles2/*.txt')
for files in data:
    print(files)
    
    for file in data2:
        print(file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the filenames in `dir2` are the same as in `dir1`, so you don't need to list both directories. Just attach the filename you found to the second dir.

```
from pathlib import Path

dir1 = Path('/home/liu/Music/datafiles1')
dir2 = Path('/home/liu/Music/datafiles2')

for filepath1 in dir1.glob('*.txt'):
    filepath2 = dir2 / filepath1.name
    print(filepath1, filepath2)
```

Comment: i am getting error while trying to open the file /home/liu/Music/datafiles1/data_file_001.txt        using a = open("filepath1","r").how can it be solved...please

Comment: `filepath1.open()` to open the file or `filepath1.read_text()` to read everything into a string directly. Here is the [documentation of pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text)

Comment: Thanks...it s quite fine

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to write:

```py
import glob
data1=glob.glob('/home/liu/Music/datafiles1/*.txt')
data2=glob.glob('/home/liu/Music/datafiles2/*.txt')
for files in zip(data1, data2):
    f1, f2 = files
    print(f1, f2)
```

Your scheme of nested loops means that `data2` becomes exhausted.

Comment: let me check @quamrana

Comment: can we define x=f1 and y=f2  so that it would be easier  for me for further calculation....any other way can we do it

Comment: Did you mean: `x, y = files`? They are your variables. Name them as you wish.

Comment: yes...if i have file that contain some string can we np.loadtxt  using ur code

Comment: however i defined x= f1 , then i tried a = open("x","r")
    b = a.readlines()
    a.close()

Comment: can u please tell me how to access x through  open....readlines

Comment: You are now asking a different question. Please create a brand new question with all these new details.

Comment: Yes, different. You mentioned ‘open()’ above, just not in your original question.